# Django how to create an invoice model from vehicle model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model called vehicle.

```py
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
```

the following is sample data stored.

```
id name    price
1  cycle   100
2  bus     10000
3  car     1000
```

Now i want make invoice based on the order. Someone orders for 2-cycles, 1 bus and 3 cars.

I want to have a model  named Invoice which will have 2-cycles, 1 bus and 3 cars. in it.

and at the end create the invoice in the browser like below:

```
id  vehicles  no_of_ordered  unit_price  total_price 
1    cycles        2           100           200
2    bus           1           1000          1000
3    car           3           10000         30000
```

How to create the model:

```py
class Invoice(models.Model):
    vehicles = models.ManyToManyField(Vehicle, null=True, blank=True)
```

After that how to create that list of invoice using the above model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create two models representing your invoice and invoice positions. The `Invoice` model would hold general information (for example a date or the corresponding user) and the `InvoicePosition` model would hold the instance of `Vehicle` and the ordered quantity. You could also add the unit price so your previous invoices won't be incorrect after you changed a vehicle's price.

Here's my suggestion in code:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    pass

class InvoicePosition(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, related_name='invoice_positions', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, related_name='vehicle_positions', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    # You could use the price field to cache the price when the invoice was issued.
    price = models.models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
```

Here's a complete example creating vehicles and an invoice like in your example:

```
cycle = Vehicle.objects.create(name='cycle', price=100)
bus = Vehicle.objects.create(name='bus', price=10000)
car = Vehicle.objects.create(name='car', price=1000)

invoice = Invoice.objects.create()
invoice.invoice_positions.create(vehicle=cycle, quantity=2, price=cycle.price)
invoice.invoice_positions.create(vehicle=bus, quantity=1, price=bus.price)
invoice.invoice_positions.create(vehicle=car, quantity=3, price=car.price)
```

Comment: i will try it. I am new to Django. What is pass

Comment: [`pass`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) is a Python statement that does nothing. I used it here because I didn't want to add any fields to the `Invoice` model. But just the first line would be syntactically incorrect since it's not a complete class definition.

Comment: `# You could use the price field to cache the price when the invoice was issued.` can you show how to do it

Comment: I updated my answer to include an example of how you could re-create your example. As you can see, I save the price of the vehicles when creating an invoice. This way, you can change the price of a vehicle later but he past invoices will keep using the former prices.

Comment: If i update the vehicle object. it should reflect, Like i change the car name to Carsmall and change the rate etc. so what do you suggest the best way

Comment: Unfortunately, that question is way too broad for me to give a helpful answer, sorry. Please try to create an example demonstrating your problem and post it as a new question. :)

Also, I can't recommend the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/) enough. It's very comprehensive and often has code examples.